# Should the "study" and "learning" tags be made synonyms?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tag-synonyms

The tags [study](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/study) and [learning](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/learning) seem to cover the same area as far as I can see. Should we make them synonyms?

If not can we clarify what is different about them so people can choose between them correctly?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, I think they should.  I can't imagine anyone being interested in questions tagged with one but not the other.